# how to make about us file in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-url

hi I am new in codeigniter. I have welcome.php file. so please tell me that how I can create more files like about us.
I created about_us.php in views and aboutus.php in application/controllers/aboutus.php

I am accessing file with this url localhost/restaurent_templatescodeg/index.php/about_us

but 404 Page Not Found message display.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Copy welcome.php to about_us.php and change the name of the class to About_Us. Make a view (just php and/or html output) in the views folder and load it via the controller.

Comment: I realize that has been a while, but could you please mark this as answered if it fixed your issue? Thanks.